# TestMain - no tests to run

Tags: go, testing

I am writing a package which compiles a C source file and writes the output to another file. I am writing tests for this package, and I need to create a temporary directory to write the output files. I am using `TestMain` function to do this. For some reason, I always get the warning "no tests to run" when I just run the `TestMain` test. I tried to debug the `TestMain` function and I can see that the temporary directory is indeed created. When I create the `testoutput` directory manually, all tests pass.

I am loading two C source files from `testdata` directory, one of which is intentionally wrong.

gcc.go:

```
package gcc

import (
    "os/exec"
)

func Compile(inPath, outPath string) error {
    cmd := exec.Command("gcc", inPath, "-o", outPath)
    return cmd.Run()
}
```

gcc_test.go:

```
package gcc

import (
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "testing"
)

func TestOuputFileCreated(t *testing.T) {
    var inFile = filepath.Join("testdata", "correct.c")
    var outFile = filepath.Join("testoutput", "correct_out")

    if err := Compile(inFile, outFile); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Expected err to be nil, got %s", err.Error())
    }

    if _, err := os.Stat(outFile); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        t.Error("Expected output file to be created")
    }
}

func TestOuputFileNotCreatedForIncorrectSource(t *testing.T) {
    var inFile = filepath.Join("testdata", "wrong.c")
    var outFile = filepath.Join("testoutput", "wrong_out")

    if err := Compile(inFile, outFile); err == nil {
        t.Errorf("Expected err to be nil, got %v", err)
    }

    if _, err := os.Stat(outFile); os.IsExist(err) {
        t.Error("Expected output file to not be created")
    }
}

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    os.Mkdir("testoutput", 666)
    code := m.Run()
    os.RemoveAll("testoutput")
    os.Exit(code)
}
```

`go test` output:

```
sriram@sriram-Vostro-15:~/go/src/github.com/sriram-kailasam/relab/pkg/gcc$ go test
--- FAIL: TestOuputFileCreated (0.22s)
        gcc_test.go:14: Expected err to be nil, got exit status 1
FAIL
FAIL    github.com/sriram-kailasam/relab/pkg/gcc        0.257s
```

Running `TestMain`:

```
Running tool: /usr/bin/go test -timeout 30s github.com/sriram-kailasam/relab/pkg/gcc -run ^(TestMain)$

ok      github.com/sriram-kailasam/relab/pkg/gcc    0.001s [no tests to run]
Success: Tests passed.
```

Comment: You can't run just `TestMain`, it's not a test. `TestMain` runs all the other tests.

Comment: I see. But I still don't know why I get an error if I create a temporary directory, but it works when I create it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odds are, your problems are around the *mode* value you're passing to `os.Mkdir(...)`. You're providing `666` decimal, which is `01232` octal (or if you prefer, a *permissions* string of `d-w--wx-wT`) which I assume is not really what you're looking for.

Instead of `666`, you should specify `0666` -- the leading 0 indicates your value is in octal notation.

---

Also, your two tests are virtually identical; instead of using a `TestMain(...)` to perform your setup, I'd suggest using `*T.Run(...)` to execute your tests from a single, top-level `Test*` func.  Something like this:

gcc_test.go:

```
package gcc

import (
  "testing"
  "path/filepath"
  "os"
)

const testoutput = "testoutput"

type testcase struct {
  inFile  string
  outFile string
  err     error
}

func (tc *testcase) test(t *testing.T) {
  var (
    in  = filepath.Join("testdata", tc.inFile)
    out = filepath.Join(testoutput, tc.outFile)
  )

  if err := Compile(in, out); err != tc.err {
    t.Errorf("Compile(%q, %q) == %v; Wanted %v", in, out, err, tc.err)
  }
}

func TestCompile(t *testing.T) {
  os.Mkdir(testoutput, 0666)

  tests := map[string]*testcase{
    "correct": &testcase{"correct.c", "correct_out", nil},
    "wrong":   &testcase{"wrong.c", "wrong_out", expectedError},
  }

  for name, tc := range tests {
    t.Run(name, tc.test)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that I did not have permission to write to `testoutput` with `0666` mode. I changed it to `0777` and all the tests passed.

Answer (score 5):

**#1**

Trying to run `TestMain()` is like trying to run `main()`. You don't do that, the OS does this for you.

[TestMain](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Main) was introduced in Go 1.4 to help with the setup/teardown of the test environment and is called instead of running the tests; quoting the release notes:

> If the test code contains a function
>
> ```
> func TestMain(m *testing.M)
> ```
>
> that function will be called instead of running the tests directly. The M struct contains methods to access and run the tests.

---

**#2**

Use `ioutil.TempDir()` to create temporary directories.

```
tmpDir, err := ioutil.TempDir("", "test_output")
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}
```

It will take care of creating the directory. You should later use `os.Remove(tmpDir)` to remove the temporary directory.

You can use it along with a *slightly modified* version of the suggestion from [Tim Peoples](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2924307/tim-peoples), an example would be:

```
func TestCompile(t *testing.T) {
    tmpDir, err := ioutil.TempDir("", "testdata")
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }
    defer os.Remove(tmpDir)

    tests := []struct {
        name, inFile, outFile string
        err                   error
    }{
        {"OutputFileCreated", "correct.c", "correct_out", nil},
        {"OutputFileNotCreatedForIncorrectSource", "wrong.c", "wrong_out", someErr},
    }

    for _, test := range tests {
        var (
            in  = filepath.Join("testdata", test.inFile)
            out = filepath.Join(tmpDir, test.outFile)
        )

        t.Run(test.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            err = Compile(in, out)
            if err != test.err {
                t.Errorf("Compile(%q, %q) == %v; Wanted %v", in, out, err, test.err)
            }
        })
    }
}
```